# Remove html autofocus use javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autofocus

Here's my full code:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which,
    value    = $(this).val()

    if (code==13 && value!=''){
        $('.with-header').show()

        var secondaryContent = 'secondary-content',
        materialIcons        = 'material-icons',
        conllectiontItem     = 'collection-item'

        $('ul').append('<li class='+conllectiontItem+'>\
            <span class="words">'+value+'</span>\
            <span href="#" class='+secondaryContent+'>\
            <a class="'+materialIcons+' done">done</a>\
            <a class="'+materialIcons+' delete">delete</a>\
            <a class="'+materialIcons+' edit">edit</a>\
            </span></li>')

        //this to empty input
        $(this).val('')
    }
})

$('body').on('click', '.done', function(){
    $(this).parents('.collection-item').toggleClass('lineThrough')
})

$('body').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var edit = $(this).parent().prev().html('<input class="listInput">')
})

$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $(this).parents('.collection-item').remove()
})

$('body').on('keypress','.listInput', function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which,
    value    = $(this).val()

    if (code==13 && value!=''){
        $(this).parent().html(value)
    }
})
```

Sorry I'm still beginner and I use materialize css framework, so it's kinda complicate to append.

What am I trying to do is making to do list which every list can be edit by clicking a button with class '.edit' and I want to give an autofocus into the list that was appended with `<input>`, but the autofocus only work once. I guess it's because I put the autofocus for every '.listInput'.

So after I append the html input, and I am done editing the list, I want to try remove the 'autofocus' from '.listInput' but I don't know how to do it?

can you help me with it or do you have another solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit', function(){        
  $toEdit = $(this).parent().prev();
  $toEdit.html('<input class="listInput">')
  $toEdit.focus();
});
```

Comment: `html('<input class="listInput"> ')`
this code is where I want to put the autofocus.
It's like when I click on `'.edit'` the code above replace a html in listInput and have autofocus

Comment: Are you trying to put a focus to an input element? Because the html() returns HTML, not a Jquery object to apply the .focus()

Comment: yes, I am trying to put it into input element so I don't need to move my cursor to the input. I want to everytime I click on '.edit' and the html change into input element, it's autofocus on it.

Comment: updated to my full js code sir.. And I need to use `$('body').on(...)` in every code after my keypress function. If I don't use it, the code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur() function to remove the focus from the element.

For example to remove focus on all the textbox use below code. You can use this with different scenario.

```
$(function()

   $('input').blur();

  });
```